# Extend left side of a div within a centered container

Tags: html, css

I want to extend the left side of a navigation menu within a centered container. I tried `position: absolute` but the menu overlapped the logo,
is there another solution? If not, how can I stop an absolute element overlapping other elements?

Here is an image of what I'm trying to do
[extended div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygF6D.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your menu elements inside the container, you can go with an absolute `::before` pseudo-element.

```css
section {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eaeaea
}

header {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 30px;
}

nav {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2);
  position: relative;
}

nav::before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  right: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <nav>navigation menu</nav>
    <span>logo</span>
  </header>

container
</section>
```